# How to solve $7^n\equiv 1 \pmod {180}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I've used Euler's theorem: $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod m$, where $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime.

and I got: $7^{48}\equiv 1 \pmod{180}$.

My question is: Is there a smaller $n$ satisfies the equation: $7^n\equiv 1 \pmod{180}$?

For example: By using Euler's theorem to solve $2^n\equiv 1 \pmod{15}$
             we get: $2^8\equiv 1 \pmod{15}$, where $n=8$.
             However, $2^4\equiv 1 \pmod{15}$ also satisfies the equation where $n=4$.

How to find the smallest $n$?

Comment: Please could you retype it correctly in latex

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! To find the smallest number $n$, you need the so-called order of $7$ modulo $180$. It must be a divisor of $\phi(180)=48$ ($\phi$ denotes the totient-function).

Comment: the smallest is $12.$ Just saying. Note that $180 = 4 \cdot 9 \cdot 5.$ You do each prime (or prime power) separately, then combine as the LCM of those results.

Comment: The smallest $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ for which $7^n\equiv 1\pmod{180}$ is called the multiplicative order of $7$ mod $180$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find $n$, first try $24=\frac{48}{2}$. We are succesful, so we try $12=\frac{24}{2}$. Success again. The prime divisors of $12$ are $2$ and $3$, so you only need to check $6$ and $4$, which are not successful.

Comment: You could've been unlucky and tried $\frac{48}{3} = 16$ first, which does _not_ work. Then do $24$.

Comment: @Arthur That would not be "unlucky", as then after $24$ (or $12$) you would not have to check $8$ (or $4$) anymore as you already know that the order of $7$ contains a factor $3$. Regardless of the choices, you always need to check $4$ other numbers to conclude that $12$ is the order of $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Try working  modulo the prime powers that make up $180$. Note that $180$ is $2^2 \times 3^2 \times 5$.

- Modulo $2^2$ you get that $7^n$ is $1$ if $n$ is a multiple of $2$ (and it is easy to see it is an only if).
- Modulo $5$ you get that $7^n$ is $1$ if $n$ is a multiple of $4$, and it is not hard to see it is an only if by checking $7^2$ is not $1$.
- Modulo $3^2$ you get that $7^n$ is $1$ if $n$ is a multiple of $6$. Yet in fact $7^3$ is already $1$ too. But $7^2$ is not $1$.

Putting this together you get that modulo $180$ the $n$ for which $7^n$ is $1$ are  multiples of the LCM of $2,4,3$ that is $12$.

Note, if your know it you could also use Carmichael's $\lambda$ function  instead of $\varphi$ to get the upper bound of $12$ right away.

Comment: Nitpick: $7^3$ *is* $1$ modulo $3^2$.

Comment: Thanks! That's a bit embarrassing; it seems I did not check carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \bmod n$ for $(a,n)=1$ by Euler's theorem, we have $7^{48}\equiv 1\bmod 180$, and we can check the divisors $d$ of $48$, whether or not $7^d\equiv 1\bmod 180$ holds. This follows from the fact, that the order of $a$ divides an exponent $m$ with $a^m\equiv 1$. Now $24$ and $12$ do work, but smaller ones do not work.